# SQL Query with grouping Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL query that pull data from the SQL Server. I need to group a field (Alpha field) and if there are more than one record, display 'NO MATCH'. This query will help users spot jobs with a missing Alpha value.

Here is the query to get the data with the grouping:

```
select name,Alpha from T
where name = 'John'
GROUP BY name, Alpha
```

Here are the results from the query:

```
name    Alpha
John    4
John    7
John    20
```

I am trying to get the result to say 'NO MATCH' if the data doesn't match. The example above have three records that do not match. How do I get the result to be 'No match'? If all records are a match display the alpha value.

Here is the link to the SQL Fiddle I created with the example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccd77/1/0

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I don't understand. It seems they *all* match, what do you mean thet don't match?

Comment: @Charlieface the Alpha values are different in the example above. It's 4,7 and 20. I want to display 'NO MATCH' when the alpha values are different and when they are the same to display the Alpha value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly more performant to use `MIN = MAX` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT`.

This has the same result in this case, but does not require a sort on `Alpha`.

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  IIF(MIN(Alpha) = MAX(Alpha), CAST(MAX(Alpha) AS VARCHAR(12)), 'No Matched') AS Alpha
FROM T
WHERE name = 'John'
GROUP BY
  name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two more records having same `Alpha` filed:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (26, 'Andy',  15) ;
INSERT INTO t VALUES (27, 'Andy',  15) ;
```

You can use COUNT with DISTINCT to check if all values are the same:

```
select name
      ,IIF(COUNT(DISTINCT Alpha) = 1, CAST(MAX(Alpha) AS VARCHAR(12)), 'No Matched') AS Alpha
from T
--where name = 'John'
GROUP BY name
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: `IIF(MIN(Alpha) = MAX(Alpha)` gets the same result and does not require sorting on `Alpha`